# Detecting file systems error, stuck, i cannot continue to install ubuntu "unhandled action bin" error

Tags: usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu latest version (ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64) to a old Dell laptop (dual core, 4 GB RAM), together with a preexisting Win10 installation.

I'm stuck at installation.

I get this error in the log:

on sys/
ubuntu upowerd[2840]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000:00:04.0/usb3/3-4 and so on.

Here a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0SiK.jpg)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you verify your ISO download  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) and verify/check your install media integrity before.  If a single-bit is wrong you're looking at heartache, and these checks that take a 60-120 secs but saves hours of diagnosing problems if either download or write failed. I'd suggest you check these steps first (I would in your situation; esp. check install media).

Comment: Maybe take you 60/120 second, to me the instruction look like Egyptian! all i wanted was a easy way to install ubuntu as dual boot and silly me i guess in 2019 will be easy to install it in a laptop where i can install windows 7/8/10 with no issue at all :D I doubt the download of the iso was corrupted, i have a 500mbit optic cable, never have issue of corrupted files, maybe the usb, i will try to download from another source, torrent maybe instead of the ubuntu website, and i will try top use another usb stick.

Comment: My primary suggest was the to check install media (ie. confirm the write was successful).  It's easy - you press a key when you see the something-in-rectangle & person-in-circle & menu appears; you select the check-install -disc [check-install-media] option at the menu.  This takes 1-2 secs; the rest is waiting for the check to complete (50+ secs depending on speed of device)  That doesn't require skill; and documentation is available if you look (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck - pictures are for older version though).  These are steps you do with windows too.

Comment: I've added a quickie beginners guide to checking your .iso download.

Comment: ok guiverc, now i understood, so i check the usb media, "no errors found". So both usb and iso are fine!

Comment: searching on google seems /sys/devices/pci0000:00/000:00:04.0/usb3/ is about usb port (im not sure, but if usb3 mean usb 3.0 is an error, this laptop have only 2.0 ports), so if is something about the usb port, i will try tomorrow to install from a dvd, hoping will not happen this error.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue!

Bluetooth was causing the error, I disabled it in BIOS and the installation proceed without issue.

Sadly Ubuntu didn't give me a more useful error message about what exactly was the issue, so I had to try 1000 things before I stumbled into a post about somebody with bind/unbind errors and tried his fix.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This worked for me too.

Comment: I've tried many many solutions. Only this lighten me. For my HP Elite x2 1012 G2, it's about wireless module. After disabling `WLAN Quick Conneet` / `Wireless Network Devie (WLAN)` / `Bluetooth` / `Mobile Network Device` in BOIS, I can install Ubuntu 20.04.5 finally. But I've tried the latest Majanro & Ubuntu 22.04.1 there is no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

To check that the .iso file that you downloaded is correct and error free...

- go to the download directory where you got your .iso, [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/)
- download either the **md5sums** file (or sha256sums file)
- in the terminal, "cd /path_to_iso_file" (ie: cd ~/Desktop), then type "**md5sum 18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso**" (or "sha256sum 18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso")
- this will yield a long number
- open the **md5sums** (or sha256sums) file in any editor you like, and compare the number you got above, with the contents of the md5sums (or sha256sums) file, and they should match, and if they do match, you got a good download

To check your Ubuntu Live DVD/USB...

- boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- hit any key to access the menu
- select "Check CD for Defects" from the menu

Comment: ok, i was able to download fciv.exe from microsoft site and verify the m5d hash, is the same exsact as ubuntu website! thanks to all!